# Ansible dynamic inventory on GCE: success command not found

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine

I am trying to configure my Ansible for dynamic inventory. According to the [ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html) I am typing on my OS X laptop command line:

```
GCE_INI_PATH=~/.gce.ini ansible all -i gce.py -m setup hostname | success >> {"ansible_facts": {"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": ["x.x.x.x"],
```

and I am getting:

```
-bash: success: command not found
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

What should I type instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just running the command

```
GCE_INI_PATH=~/.gce.ini ansible all -i gce.py -m setup
```

if this works you will get a stream of JSON output (from the Ansible `setup` module) showing the system information about any GCE hosts you have set up.